# My Github pages won't apply the custom css file to the website

Tags: html, css, github

I've tried to upload my custom CSS file to apply to https://soundoffmusic.com/

I've got the raw CSS file with this file path

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/themomoravi/SoundOff-Website/master/styles.css
```

and I've tried using this as my `href` since it points directly to the raw CSS file:

```
href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/themomoravi/SoundOff-Website/master/styles.css">
```

Still it has not worked. I've also tried the abbreviated versions of this such as `styles.css`, `SoundOff-Website/styles.css`, etc. (as my `href`).
I'm wondering why else `github` pages might not be rendering my custom CSS.

Please advise and thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are serving your website from a GitHub repository using GitHub pages (which I assume you are doing, judging by the raw link you provided), you can (and should) reference your assets in a relative way, such as

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
```

in your `index.html`'s `<head>`.

Linking directly to GitHub raw storage can cause problems as it is not designed as a CDN and everything is always returned with a `plain/text` header. There used to be a [service](https://rawgit.com/) that provided a solid bridge between a client and raw GH storage, but it's been shut down and GitHub pages work just as well now.